# Unable to connect to mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm following this book [addyosmani - backbone-fundamentals](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-2-book-library---your-first-restful-backbone.js-app) for creating a simple backbone.js app with node server and mongodb as backend.

As instructed, I've installed the latest versions of Node.js from[nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/download/) and mongodb from [www.mongodb.org](http://www.mongodb.org/) and ran mongodb by followed the [instructions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/).

---

The `package.json` is as follows:

```
    {
    "name": "backbone-library",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "A simple library application using Backbone",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~3.1.0",
        "path": "~0.4.9",
        "mongoose": "~3.5.5",
        "body-parser": "~1.9.1"
    }
}
```

The [tutorial then suggests to](http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#connect-to-the-database) add the following to `server.js` file for connection to mongoDB:

```
//Connect to database
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database' );

//Schemas
var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    author: String,
    releaseDate: Date
});

//Models
var BookModel = mongoose.model( 'Book', Book );
```

I've got confused with the following line:

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database' );
```

because the book doesn't mention anything regarding creating a database named `library_database` and I haven't created manually - Still if I run the following in `server.js`:

```
mongoose.createConnection( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database' );

var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
// we wait till mongo is ready before letting the http handler query users:
db.once('open', function () {
    console.log('Running');
    //Schemas
    var Book = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        author: String,
        releaseDate: Date
    });

    //Models
    var BookModel = mongoose.model('Book', Book);
});
```

It logs `Running`..! (*how come because I didn't create any `library_database`..?*)

But, If I further follow the book by adding a GET request handler as shown below:

```
    //Get a list of all books
app.get( '/api/books', function( request, response ) {
    return BookModel.find( function( err, books ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return response.send( books );
        } else {
            return console.log( err );
        }
    });
});
```

and hit it with the following request:

```
jQuery.get( '/api/books/', function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
  console.log( 'Get response:' );
  console.dir( data );
  console.log( textStatus );
  console.dir( jqXHR );
});
```

According to the tutorial I'm supposed to see the logs, Instead I get the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:4711/api/books/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

The DB is currently listening to default port with the default database "test".

I tried `use library_database` in mongo shell, but still get the same response from the node server.

Do I need to manually create a db for the application..? If so, how can I create an instance for the app and connect to it from node server..?

Or does mongoose automatically creates such a db in the applications root folder (*very unlikely to happen*)..?

I'm pretty new to `node.js`, `mongodb`, `mongoose` etc so I might be missing some basic concepts. What am I missing..?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the examples for [`connect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-connect) and [`createConnection`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection) in the docs:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:pass@localhost:port/database');
//-----------------------------------------------^
```

The one in tutorial is as follows:

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost/library_database' );
```

It is missing the port number. I changed it by adding default port number as follows:

```
mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/library_database');
```

and now I'm getting the response!

Comment: port number is required in certain mongodb versions like 3.0+  It worked after adding port no. Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

You may try to write 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. This has solved my issue.

Instead of

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newdbcoll');
```

try this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/newdbcoll');
```

Comment: You could have add some explanation or sample code.

Answer (score 3):

You might find this helpful from [mongoose documentation](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose)

> Important! If you opened a separate connection using
>   mongoose.createConnection() but attempt to access the model through
>   mongoose.model('ModelName') it will not work as expected since it is
>   not hooked up to an active db connection. In this case access your
>   model through the connection you created:
>
> var conn = mongoose.createConnection('your connection string')   ,
>   MyModel = conn.model('ModelName', schema)   , m = new MyModel;
>   m.save(); // works vs
>
> var conn = mongoose.createConnection('your connection string')   ,
>   MyModel = mongoose.model('ModelName', schema)   , m = new MyModel;
>   m.save(); // does not work b/c the default connection object was never
>   connected

Answer (score 1):

**This is how I have connected.**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose/');
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newdbcoll');


//e.g. mongodb://username:server@mongoserver:10059/somecollection
//mongoose_auth: 'mongodb://admin:admin@127.0.0.1:27017/chrome-server'
```

And I am able to connect.

Comment: here if 'newdbcoll' db is not present in mongodb then a new db with the same name is created or it throws an error?

Comment: @RahulSharma It will not throw any type or error, when you will insert a doc in a collection, DB will be created.

Comment: Hey I am stocked in a situation,  I am using collection for user data handling. Few days back it was fine and formatted my machine, so DB got deleted. Now If I try  for  signup, Since there is new DB, Mongodb findOne query never returns. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Charlie, Are you using mongoose ODM or any other..... 
Can you also please specify the version you are using? I think that will help to replicate the error.

Comment: @Varun: thank you for response , I am new to node and I am not clear what is mongoose ODM. my package.json has     "mongodb": "^2.2.35" and
    "mongoose": "^4.13.12" .

Answer (score 0):

this is your best mistake

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://localhost:{port}/library_database' );
```

so give you full part of localhost like that

```
mongoose.connect( 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:{port}/library_database' );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, just wrapped code in an `async function` and made sure to `await` the `connect()` functions before using them. Now everything works as expected! Hope this helps someone who might be facing the same issue.